# Facebook Graph API and FQL return different data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-sharer

I am using Facebook's FQL on my website to pull the 'Share' count for a number of items. Recently it has stopped counting new shares. Graph API tends to report the correct value (sometimes..?) and FQL reports 0 no matter what. I am using the 'sharer' popup on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the reason it was not counting shares is because I was using an alternate format for the Share URL which contained p[title], p[url], etc. The supported method which will count shares is as below.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
    Share on Facebook
</a>
```